# python regular expressions: html

Tags: python, html, regex

I have a html file that contains a line:

```
a = '<li><a href="?id=11&amp;sort=&amp;indeks=0,3" class="">H</a></li>'
```

When I search:

```
re.findall(r'href="?(\S+)"', a)
```

I get expected output:

```
['?id=11&amp;sort=&amp;indeks=0,3']
```

However, when I add "i" to the pattern like:

```
re.findall(r'href="?i(\S+)"', a)
```

I get:

```
[ ]
```

Where's the catch? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use a parser instead of regex. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1219006

Comment: While the above link is certainly true for parsing HTML, the question is asking to find lines containing `href=?`--a task sufficiently simple for regex, IMHO. Rather, using an HTML parser here could be considered overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `?` has a special meaning and is not being matched literally.

To fix, change your regex like so:

```
re.findall(r'href="\?i(\S+)"', a)
```

Otherwise, the `?` is treated as the optional modified applied to the `"`. This happens to work (by accident) in your first example, but doesn't work in the second.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. However I do need to search patterns that I have already extracted from elsewhere, so it would be time consuming to change the pattern by hand. Is there a way to make python disregard "?" characters (and others with special meaning) in the pattern?

Comment: @priilane: Yes, by escaping the pattern first. http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape

Answer (score 4):

I personally think that Python's built-in HTMLParser is incredibly useful for cases like these. I don't think this is overkill at all -- I think it's *vastly* more readable and maintainable than a regex.

```
>>> class HrefExtractor(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
...     def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
...         if tag == 'a':
...             attrs = dict(attrs)
...             if 'href' in attrs:
...                 print attrs['href']
... 
>>> he = HrefExtractor()
>>> he.feed('<a href=foofoofoo>')
foofoofoo
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch here is that `?` has a special meaning in regexes, it defines zero or one occurrence of anything. So, if you want the href value from the `<a>` tag, you should be using -

```
re.findall(r'href="(\?\S+)"', a)
```

and not

```
re.findall(r'href="?(\S+)"', a)
```

So, if you're not using ?'s special meaning, the you should escape it like `\?` or use it like `ab?` which says either a or b. Your way of using ? is improper.